# How to draw a box in java inside which various shapes can be drawn?

Tags: java

I am using paint method to draw shapes . But I want those shapes to appear inside a box whose by deafault colour is white . How do i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [the Sun/Oracle tutorial on this very subject](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html).

Comment: Can I have a small code as example ? Or a link to some sample code . Not able to find some sample code to work on .